# OData v4 with C#- search.in not works

Tags: c#, odata, .net-6.0, webapi, edmx

I trying use $filter parameter with value Channels/any(t: search.in(t,'A,B', ',')). But in OData V4 i have this error message

```
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. An unknown function with name 'search.in' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.",
```

Any suggestion to resolve this?

my endpoint `...$filter=Channels/any(t: search.in(t,'A,B', ','))`

my model property Channels is defined this way `public string[]? Channels { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

[`search.in` is an operator supported by Azure AI Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-search-in-function) and isn't part of the OData specification.

For ASP.NET Core's OData package, you would need to use an OData `$filter` expression with [the `in` operator](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/cs01/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-cs01-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc505773230), e.g.:

```
Example 56: all products whose name value is ‘Milk’ or ‘Cheese’:

http://host/service/Products?$filter=Name in ('Milk', 'Cheese')
```